# Retrieve Trigger-generated UID from Laravel in save method

Tags: php, laravel

my situation is that I am not using **auto-incrementing** id in my model.

Instead, I am using a **string uid**, g**enerated automatically by a MySQL trigger**.

So, when I create a model, for instance

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar = "bar";
$foo->save();
echo $foo->id; // null
```

My id is null. This happens because my `public $incrementing` must be set to false.

How would I retrieve this **trigger saved** value at `save()`?

Comment: Could something like [`Model->fresh()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fresh) do the trick?

Comment: @Bytewave it return `null`, probably because it doesn't find the record without the ID.

Comment: @Luiz, have you tried `create()` method, `Foo::create(['bar' => 'bar']);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading the [API of Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) (assuming you are using this version), and there what I found:

`array getDirty()` method:

```php
$foo->save();
$newAttributes = $foo->getDirty();
dd($newAttributes); // dump an array.
```

`void refresh()` method:

```
$foo->save();
$foo->refresh();
dd($foo->id)
```

The last solution, find your instance with `where()` from the QueryBuilder :

```
$foo->save();
Foo::where('bar', $foo->bar)
    ->where('toto', $foo->toto)
    /* ... */
    ->get();
dd($foo->id);
```